# Woocommerce hidden fields with meta keys and values. how?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Im trying to make a Frontend Publisher work with woocommerce, and need to set three hidden Meta Key fields with values. How do I go about doing that?

The meta is:

```
_manage_stock:yes
_stock:1
_visibility:visible
```

Answer (score -1):

Query: Where extactly do you want this hidden fields to be placed? in single product page/Shop page/Archive page or any other.

As per your request have tried some code and it gives me the result i.e the values for manage stock , stock and visiblity. The code is as follows

```
global $woocommerce;
$product=new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
echo $product->get_stock_quantity();
echo $product->is_visible();
echo $product->managing_stock();
```

Replace get_the_ID() with the code by which you can pass the product id. So for that product is data will be fetched and echoed. Concatenate the html in the echo statement to make them values for a hidden field. This will work for you.